# Receiving error when clearing screen in a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, sh, replit

When trying to clear the screen in Python, I get this error:

```
sh: symbol lookup error: /nix/store/41dj1v3qz9a5kjncpkxhmq50yg9r24dn-glibc-2.33-62/lib/libdl.so.2: undefined symbol: _dl_catch_error_ptr, version GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

I tried fixing it with the following code (without success):

```
import os

if name == 'nt':
  _ = os.system('cls')
else:
  _ = os.system('clear')
```

I'm currently running the code on replit, could this be the reason for it not working?

Comment: “I'm currently running the code on replit, could this be the reason for it not working?” - What happens when you run it locally in a ‘proper’ Python environment?

Comment: Why are you getting an `sh` error from running a Python script?

Comment: @martineau Seems to happen due to running it on Replit.

Comment: @S3DEV It works when running it locally…

Comment: Sounds like a Replit issue…so contact them and see if there is a way to do it.

Comment: From this discussion [How can you clear the console?](https://replit.com/talk/ask/How-can-you-clear-the-console/11453) it sounds like a Replit bug and the workaround is to `import replt` then `replit.clear()` — unfortunately that's not portable (and some folks said even that didn't work).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you need to write `os.name` instead of `name`,

So like this

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    os.system('cls')
else:
    os.system('clear')
```

To clear the screen, you can write your program in a way that is compatible with all systems by briefly using the following,

```
import os

os.system('cls|clear')
```

Answer (score 1):

It just seems to be a replit issue.

This happens to me when using '*os*' for anything.

like ***martineau*** said you gotta import '*replit*'.

```
import replit
replit.clear()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).